# Using my Chrome extension's dev version on one machine and prod on another

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension. I'm also a user of my chrome extension. As a user, I have the prod version of my extension installed in chrome from the chrome webstore.

As a developer, I have the development version of the chrome extension installed locally via `Load unpacked` on my dev machine.

That machine lists my extension twice, once for the unpacked dev version and once for the prod version. How can I be sure that I'm testing with the dev version on my dev machine?

**Do I need to disable the prod version on that machine?** I don't want to disable it if it can be avoided because I have sync extensions enabled (which I don't want to change) and disabling it on one machine will disable it across all my other machines.

Comment: Normally one would have different profile where dev version is installed. For example, VSCode debugger creates new profile for each new project, so there is no conflict. In Edge it seems disabling prod extension on one machine, doesn't disable it on another synced machine, chrome syncs differently?